# How to apply all objects of a list to a function which mutates a dplyr tibble?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set of variables which I want to perform some standard mutations to (e.g. sum, divide). I have a list which specifies which variables I want to be divided by which.

I want to know if it's possibly to apply a custom mutate function to all of the names in the list, iteratively mutating the tibble (i.e. not creating a new tibble like `lapply` would).

For example below, I want `Sepal.Width` and `Petal.Length` to be scaled by (divide) by `Sepal.Length`, and similar for `Sepal.Width`.

```r
scale_variables_by = list(Sepal.Length = c("Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length"),
                          Sepal.Width = c("Petal.Width", "Petal.Length"))
```

To do so, I have two functions. 
The first scales one variable by another and renames the new column as `"original"_"div"_"scalar"`:

```r
# Scales one variable by another
scale_by <- function(df, variables, scalar, separator = "div") {
  scalar_s <- sym(scalar)

  df %>%
    mutate_at(variables, list(temp = ~if_else(eval(scalar_s) != 0,
                                              ./eval(scalar_s),
                                              NA_real_))) %>%
    rename_at(vars(ends_with("temp")), ~paste(variables, separator, scalar, 
                                              sep = "_"))
}
```

The second takes a list, accesses all of the variables specified to be scaled by a specific variable, and scales them by that variable.

```r
# Takes a list with specified variable/scalar combinations and applies scale_by
# to them
scale_by_list <- function(df, input_list, scalar_l) {
  df %>%
    scale_by(variables = input_list[[scalar_l]], scalar = scalar_l)
}
```

Putting it all together it works like this:

```r
library(dplyr)

# Scales one variable by another
scale_by <- function(df, variables, scalar, separator = "div") {
  scalar_s <- sym(scalar)

  df %>%
    mutate_at(variables, list(temp = ~if_else(eval(scalar_s) != 0,
                                              ./eval(scalar_s),
                                              NA_real_))) %>%
    rename_at(vars(ends_with("temp")), ~paste(variables, separator, scalar, 
                                              sep = "_"))
}

# Takes a list with specified variable/scalar combinations and applies scale_by
# to them
scale_by_list <- function(df, input_list, scalar_l) {
  df %>%
    scale_by(variables = input_list[[scalar_l]], scalar = scalar_l)
}

scale_variables_by = list(Sepal.Length = c("Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length"),
                          Sepal.Width = c("Petal.Width", "Petal.Length"))

iris %>% 
  as_tibble() %>%
  scale_by_list(input_list = scale_variables_by, scalar_l = "Sepal.Length") %>%
  scale_by_list(input_list = scale_variables_by, scalar_l = "Sepal.Width") %>%
  select(Sepal.Width_div_Sepal.Length, everything())
#> # A tibble: 150 x 9
#>    Sepal.Width_div~ Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#>               <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
#>  1            0.686          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
#>  2            0.612          4.9         3            1.4         0.2
#>  3            0.681          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2
#>  4            0.674          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2
#>  5            0.72           5           3.6          1.4         0.2
#>  6            0.722          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4
#>  7            0.739          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3
#>  8            0.68           5           3.4          1.5         0.2
#>  9            0.659          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2
#> 10            0.633          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1
#> # ... with 140 more rows, and 4 more variables: Species <fct>,
#> #   Petal.Length_div_Sepal.Length <dbl>,
#> #   Petal.Width_div_Sepal.Width <dbl>, Petal.Length_div_Sepal.Width <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2019-08-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

The result is what I want (I have four new columns which have the scaled variables), except I would like to call `scale_by_list` for all objects in the list, rather than manually creating a call for each one.

`lapply` can do this however it creates multiple different tibbles in a list, which I suppose could be join but I feel like there's a better way to do it.

---

The solution I'm leaning towards for pipeability:

```r
scale_by <- function(df, variables, scalar, separator = "div") {
  scalar_s <- sym(scalar)

  df %>%
    mutate_at(variables, list(temp = ~if_else(eval(scalar_s) != 0,
                                              ./eval(scalar_s),
                                              NA_real_))) %>%
    rename_at(vars(ends_with("temp")), ~paste(variables, separator, scalar, 
                                              sep = "_")) %>%
    select(paste(variables, separator, scalar, sep = "_"))
}

iris %>%
  bind_cols(
    names(scale_variables_by) %>%
      map_dfc(scale_by_list, df = as_tibble(iris), 
              input_list = scale_variables_by))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly, you have got `scale_variables_by` list and for every element in the list you want to divide (or any other operation) it by the name of that list. We can do this using base R with `Map`

```
iris_df <- iris

new_names <- c(mapply(function(x, y) paste0(x, "_div_", y), 
                scale_variables_by, names(scale_variables_by)))

iris_df[new_names] <- do.call(cbind, Map(function(x, y) 
     iris_df[x]/iris_df[rep(y, length(x))], scale_variables_by, names(scale_variables_by)))


head(iris_df)

#Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Sepal.Width_div_Sepal.Length
#1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa                       0.6863
#2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa                       0.6122
#3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa                       0.6809
#4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa                       0.6739
#5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa                       0.7200
#6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa                       0.7222


#  Petal.Length_div_Sepal.Length Petal.Width_div_Sepal.Width Petal.Length_div_Sepal.Width
#1                        0.2745                     0.05714                       0.4000
#2                        0.2857                     0.06667                       0.4667
#3                        0.2766                     0.06250                       0.4062
#4                        0.3261                     0.06452                       0.4839
#5                        0.2800                     0.05556                       0.3889
#6                        0.3148                     0.10256                       0.4359
```

This gives the same output as your attempt and is also scalable since it will also work if you include more number of names in each list provided those names are present in your dataframe.

---

If you want to take the `tidyverse` approach, the code becomes a bit shorter with `imap`

```
iris_df[new_names] <- purrr::imap_dfc(scale_variables_by, 
                ~iris_df[.x]/iris_df[rep(.y, length(.x))])
```

which is same as using `map2` in the following way

```
iris_df[new_names] <- purrr::map2_dfc(scale_variables_by, names(scale_variables_by),
                       ~iris_df[.x]/iris_df[rep(.y, length(.x))])
```

Comment: Hmmm, that definitely works but do you see it being possible to pipe it?

Currently, I have a few of these functions and other filtering/mutations that I'm performing on a data set so it would be nice to use this in a piped way.

Comment: @tbbarr I don't see the need to pipe here since piping would be needed only when there are chain of operations to perform. Here, everything is done within one command itself. I have added a `purrr` variant to the answer as well.

Comment: The solution I'm leaning towards using, because I effectively need it for piping since I do have a chain of operations to perform before/after this, is changing the `scale_by_list` function to only select the columns it creates then binding those to the existing tibble (see the edit to my post).

Comment: @tbbarr so something like this would work? `iris_df %>%
  bind_cols(scale_variables_by %>%
  imap_dfc(~iris_df[.x]/iris_df[rep(.y, length(.x))]))` ? You can continue your piping from there.

Comment: Yep, exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks